# NDK c++ r15 what does this warning mean?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

After switching my ndk from r12 to r15, my solution in visual studio throws these warnings in clang and gcc.

> C:\NVPACK\android-ndk-r15c\sysroot\usr\include\stdio.h(70,20):  note: in expansion of macro '__INTRODUCED_IN'
>      extern FILE* stdin __INTRODUCED_IN(23);
>
> C:\NVPACK\android-ndk-r15c\sysroot\usr\include\android\versioning.h(20,89): warning : 'annotate' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
>      #define **INTRODUCED_IN(api_level) __attribute**((annotate("introduced_in=" #api_level)))
>
> C:\NVPACK\android-ndk-r15c\sysroot\usr\include\stdio.h(70,20):  note: in expansion of macro '__INTRODUCED_IN'
>   1>   extern FILE* stdin __INTRODUCED_IN(23);
>
> ...

They are created by the versioning.h file.

What does that mean?
How do I get rid of them?

Comment: You need to update your solution. Visual Studio 2017 supports NDK r15: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/12/13/android-ndk-r15c-support-goes-in-box-in-visual-studio-2017-version-15-6-preview/

Comment: you were right, fixed reinstalling R15. It worked on VS2017, but other problems arose, so I rolled back to R15 in VS2015